# Conditions for which level sets are diffeomorphic to one another

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\pi:\mathbb R^d\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous and such that $\|\nabla\pi\|>0$ almost everywhere. Suppose that the level set $\pi^{-1}(0)$ is compact. Can I conclude that the level sets $\pi^{-1}(c)$ are diffeomorphic for all $c\geq0$?

If not, what are the additional conditions for which I can conclude it?

Thank you

Comment: $\pi(x) = |x|$? (More generally, since the empty set is compact, you probably want to assume that $\pi$ is at minimum surjective to $[0,\infty)$ for your conclusion to hold.)

Comment: Also, diffeo is certainly too strong. It shouldn't be that hard to cook up lipschitz functions with some level sets rounds spheres and some level sets the surface of a cube. For what you want (supposing you want the level sets to be $C^1$ diffeos) you need something like $\pi$ being $C^2$, that $[0,\infty)$ contains no critical value, and that $\pi$ is proper. You should look for "Morse Theory" in textbooks.

Comment: Thank you. Could not be sufficient that $\pi\in C^1$ and $\|\nabla\pi\|>0$?

Comment: Maybe. Without writing it down I am 100% sure I can prove it with C^2. With C^1 I'd actually have to think.

Comment: The same question was discussed on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914334/conditions-for-level-sets-to-be-diffeomorphic-to-each-other